How do I convert a parameter in an example table to an integer in a Cucumber feature?
If I have a feature that looks like this:
Feature: My feature
  Scenario Outline: My scenario outline.
    Given foo
    When bar
    Then I get the status code "<Status Code>".

  Examples:
   | StatusCode |
   |        200 |

and a step definition like this:
@Then("I get the status code {int}.")
Cucumber complains and says that the step is undefined, because it's expecting the type to be {string}. Is there a way to specify the type in the feature or the example table? I've looked into the TypeRegistryConfiguration but I can't work out how to make it work with feature files.

Use <Status Code> not "<Status Code>".

Or \"{int}\" if the quotes are important.

@M.P.Korstanje that was it, thank you! I didn't realise that adding the quotes would cast it to a string. If you'd like to add this as an answer I'll accept it.

It doesn't. What doess your step definition look like?

public void i_get_the_status_code(Integer expectedStatusCode). If I put the quotes back, it stops working with the same error, so they do seem to be the problem.

Ah. that's got nothing to do with casting.

Also, why use the wrapper class? This is only a status code that would very well be covered with int usage, right?

Removing the quotes around <StatusCode> as suggested by @M.P.Korstanje fixed it. After doing that, Cucumber then recognised it as an integer and picked up the step defintion.
